# В чем может быть разница между выполнением команды в CMD и через CreateProcess?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

На билд-машине установлен [R2Build](http://r2build.sourceforge.net/). Поставлена задача запускать его автоматически при срабатывании триггера. Для этих целей пишется отдельная мини-программа. R2Build можно запустить на выполнение, используя командную строку:

```
R2build.exe -r -q D:\FileName.r2p
```

При выполнении данной команды через CMD все работает. Когда же команда запускается из кода, то происходит следующее: R2Build запускается и начинает работу, но на этапе работы с SVN выдает ошибку, без объяснения причин.

```
HANDLE hChildStdoutRead;
HANDLE hChildStdoutWrite;

BOOL fSuccess;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttribute = { sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) };
saAttribute.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
saAttribute.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStdoutRead, &hChildStdoutWrite, &saAttribute, 0))
{
    return strResult;
}

STARTUPINFO sInfo = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };

sInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
if (fNeedResult)
{
    sInfo.hStdOutput = hChildStdoutWrite;
    sInfo.hStdError = hChildStdoutWrite;
}
sInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo = { 0 };

fSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL, szCommand, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &sInfo, &pInfo);
```

Мини-программа запускается с правами администратора:

```
<security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

На билд-машине установлен Windows Server 2012 R2.

В чем может быть проблема? Как можно выполнить команду из кода так, чтобы это было эквивалентно выполнению команды в CMD?

Comment: А _какую_ ошибку выдаёт SVN?

Comment: А что мешает в новом процессе запустить CMD?

Comment: По поводу ошибки SVN. Никакой ошибки нету (в логах пусто). Предположу, что это какой-то сбой самой R2Build. Проект заброшен, так что обращаться к разработчикам бесполезно.

Comment: По поводу нового процесса. Я перепробовал различные варианты. В последней попытке я поместил команду в BAT файл и через тот же самый CreateProcess запускал этот файл. Результат тот же (ошибка на этапе SVN). При этом по двойному клику по BAT файлу все работает отлично.

Comment: А пускачка собирается как консольное приложение?

Comment: Да, как консольное.

Comment: Как минимум два варианта: неверный рабочий каталог и неверные параметры командной строки. Из приведенного кода не ясно чему равно szCommand, а рабочий каталог явно не задан.

Comment: szCommand: `D:\\StartR2Build.bat FileName`; cодержимое BAT файла: `CMD /c "START "" /D "D:\R2BuildLogs\" "C:\Program Files (x86)\R2Build 2\R2build.exe" -r -q "D:\%1.r2p""`. Как я уже писал, запуск BAT файла не из кода проходит нормально. Запуск из кода идет с ошибкой на этапе SVN.